Did Newton predict the deflection of light by gravity?
In this lecture, Prof. Ganesan Srinivasan quotes Sir JJ Thompson:

The deflection of light by matter, suggested by Newton in the first of
his Queries, would itself be a result of first rate scientific
importance; it is of still greater importance when its magnitude
supports the law of gravity put forward by Einstein.

I was amazed to read this. When and where did Newton predict the deflection of light by gravity?

Michell even predicted existence of black holes based on this effect back in 1783.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29837/does-newtonian-mechanics-predict-the-bending-of-the-course-of-light-by-objects-w

Query 1 : Do not all bodies act upon light at a distance, and by their action bend its rays; and is not this action strongest at the least distance?
From The Queries, first published in 1704.

I'm not gonna give him credit for predicting gravitational lensing.  He must have been referring to something else

Reading the preceding chapter where Newton says to have experimented with this and observed fringes of colors and dark bands, makes it sound more like diffraction rather than gravitational deflection.

@jpa in that last chapter of Opticks, Newton is considering corpuscular theories to explain heat and chemistry (alchemy), specifically forces between small components of matter to explain certain phenomena. I think indeed that Newton was not thinking of gravitational lensing but in a way to explain the deflection of light when traversing matter

@jpa Thank you for your educative observation. But doesn't diffraction happen when light grazes an edge? Is it not different from "all bodies act upon light at a distance"?

@RiteshSingh It doesn't say "at any distance" though. Because of Fresnel zones, light is affected by edges up to some hundreds of micrometers away. But I don't claim to have knowledge of what Newton meant beyond what reads in the image of the page shown on Wikipedia.

Newton was a proponent of light as particles, so it seems natural that within his framework (classical mechanics) he would assume that light was affected by gravity.
This raises a pet peeve of mine, which is that scientific discourse often forgets to mention that physics (in all its wonder) is nothing more than mathematical models of the reality we measure. The above is an example where Newton was drawn to the right generic conclusion under a model that turned out not to be accurate (our current models predict that photons have no mass, so they wouldn't be gravitationally attracted under Newton's model).

Under Newtownian mechanics, wouldn't the expected change of velocity gravity causes to massless light be exactly $\frac{0}{0}$? I always thought of gravity affecting light as "filling in the undefined blank" Newton left, not contradicting him.

In classical mechanics, the gravitational attraction on a massless object is nil, as the attraction is proportional to the mass. I'm fairly sure that when Newton considered light as particles, he wasn't thinking of them as massless.

@MartinArgerami: I think Dan's argument is that F = ma, so even if F is zero, when m is also zero, a may take on any quantity. But I'm pretty sure that's just another example of Newtonian physics being unprepared for massless objects in general.

@DanStaley: There's no "exactly" $\frac00$. And that's an example of what I mean about forgetting that we are talking about models. In Newton's model, everything that moves has mass. Saying that because $F=ma$ in this case would be $0=0\times a$ allows $a$ to take any value, has no experimental basis whatsoever.

@MartinArgerami That was sort of my point. If we accept that light is massless, then Newtonian mechanics makes no predictions at all about how it would or would not move - $F = ma$ is trivially true no matter what $a$ is, which is what I meant with my "filling in a blank, not contradicting Newtownian mechanics" statement. But I suppose you're right that massless light is not how Newton himself described the universe.

@DanStaley: yes, agreed.

@DanStaley the point of the answer is that Newton didn't reason in terms of modern concepts and modern knowledge. Saying that light is massless particles implies accepting that a) light is a wave, b) it is a massless electromagnetic wave (rather than a material wave in luminiferous aether), and c) we can quantize this wave to give it some particle properties. These new quantum particles (i.e., field excitations) are something quite different from what Newton called by this word (or what a layman calls a particle) - in this sense, term elementary particle is  an equivocation.

I don't know if Newton did predict the gravitational lensing effect. However, this does not requires Einsteinian theories since gravitational acceleration does not depend on mass and therefore, does not require mass to apply.
The only reason why there might be doubt is that the speed of light needs to be finite to permit it to be deviated by gravitational acceleration and this had been demonstrated in 1676 by Ole Rømer - i.e.: 28 years before the first publication of  The Queries, mentioned by @nwr.

But according to the main theory of the time, gravitational acceleration did depend on mass...

Nope, The FORCE between two bodies depends on the mass of both: your weight on earth depend on (mass of earth and) your own mass, but the G's only depends on earth's mass (and the distance from earth gravity center). The G's on earth (in one given location) are the same (~9.81m/s²) for every one and everything including light even though it has no mass. The only reason light deviation is very small, is it's huge speed, hugely larger than earth escape velocity.

@Camion "The FORCE between two bodies depends on the mass of both", which comes from F = (G * m1 * m2) / d^2. This means if EITHER mass (in this case light) is zero then the force is zero. As has been said, according to Newton nothing massless can be affected by gravity, but he thought light had mass.

The force is irrelevant, @timchessih. The deviation is purely cinematic and is only dependant on the speed and the acceleration. a force is required to give an acceleration to a mass, but since a photon has no mass, you cannot apply a force on it and you do not need a force to accelerate it. I don't know if Newton ever believed light had a mass, but it is of no importance, since speed and acceleration are sufficient to cause a deviation and thanks to Ole Rømer, Newton knew light speed was finite.

@Camion Newtons law is $F=ma$ not $a=g$.

@Mauricio a gravitational field is expressed in m/s² and has all the kinematic characteristics of an acceleration. According to the same Newton's law you are referring to, since light has no mass, a gravitational field will accelerate it without the need of a force.

@Camion Newton's conception of forces was not based on fields, that would come up later.

You also have to propose a theory on how light couples to the field. The only known way at the time was through mass.

Fields theory is irrelevant, here, @Mauricio. The word field when I said "gravitational field" was just generic and wasn't referring to fields theory. This purely a kinematics problem. The observation is that all things submitted to earth gravitation get the same acceleration whatever their mass (depending on the distance to earth gravity center, of course). It's true for an apple, it's true for the moon, it's true for light. In the frame of newtonian mechanics, the only thing the impacts the trajectory, is the speed of the deviated body and not it's mass.

And Newton knew that perfectly, otherwise, he wouldn't have been able to formulate and solve the two body problem.
